# How to get current latest offset for each partition, then only consume up to that offset?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to check for missing keys in a topic that receives a vast amount of data.  Since the job is meant to be a run-on-demand kind of thing, it needs some criteria to know when it has searched through all the records it cares about.  We determined that this would be whatever the latest offset is for each partition at the time the job starts up.

My issue is first how to get all the partition info for the topic without actually consuming from it (I need to use this to create individual consumers for each partition that will keep track of their offset vs. the max offset).

Then second, how to stop the consumer after it sees that it has hit the max offset.

EDIT:
I found one way to get the partitions, which is to subscribe a single consumer to the topic, do a dummy `poll`, and then use `partitionsFor(...)`.  Not sure if this is the "recommended" way to do it.

Comment: As you're consuming, you'll be getting new messages... In the poll loop, you can check if the iterator is empty, and then you've reached the end

Answer (score 1):

You can able to get partitions and last offset by using consumer.partitionsFor and consumer.endOffsets

**partitionsFor**

```
 /*Get metadata about the partitions for a given topic. This method will issue a remote call to the server if it does  not already have any metadata about the given topic.*/ 
    public java.util.List<PartitionInfo> partitionsFor(java.lang.String topic)
```

**endOffsets**

```
/*Get the last offset for the given partitions. The last offset of a partition is the offset of the upcoming message, i.e. the offset of the last available message + 1*/
public java.util.Map<TopicPartition,java.lang.Long> endOffsets(java.util.Collection<TopicPartition> partitions)
```

.

Below are sample code

```
Properties consumerProperties = new Properties();
consumerProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
consumerProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "consumerid");
Consumer<String, byte[]> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(consumerProperties);    
List<PartitionInfo> parts = consumer.partitionsFor(topic);
consumer.assign(partitions);
Map<TopicPartition, Long> offsets = consumer.endOffsets(partitions);
for (TopicPartition tp : offsets.keySet()) {
    OffsetAndMetadata commitOffset = consumer.committed(new 
    TopicPartition(tp.topic(), tp.partition()));
    //Consumer offset for partition tp
    long offset=offsets.get(tp);
    //Consumed committed offset
    long consumedOffset=commitOffset.offset();
}
```